# Meaning of finite generation *over a subgroup*

Tags: group-theory, terminology, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Given a subgroup $A \leq G$, what does it mean for $A$ to be finitely generated *over the subgroup $H$?* Similarly, what does it mean for $A$ to be finitely generated *as an $H$-group?*

Comment: “Finitely generated over $H$” means that it is generated by $H$ plus a finite number of elements. “Finitely generated as an $H$-group” means that there is some action of $H$ on the subgroup, and there is a finite subset $S$ such that $A$ is the smallest subgroup that contains $S$ and is closed under the action of $H$.